# Display SQL database colums/rows in a vb textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to use a VB generated textbox to display the values/names, that are within an SQL database. I started with VB and SQL last week; I tried to use a self-built method named GetUserInfo() to display the values, but it doesnt display anything.

This is the segment used for the Textbox in VB

```
Public Class user_selection_screen
Private SQL As SQLControl
Private Authuser As String

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles box_user_selection.SelectedIndexChanged
  GetUserInfo()
End Sub

Public Sub GetUserInfo()
  SQL.RunQuery("SELECT Name" & "FROM" ""User"")

  For Each i As Object In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
    box_user_selection.Text = i.Item("Name" & vbCrLf)
  Next
End Sub
```

I started learning VB and SQL last week, so please keep the explanations as simple as possible.

Comment: What's the schema for table `User`?

Comment: you mean how the table user is set up in SQL?
Currently it has 8 columns, and 2 rows.
We created two users, Max and admin; Max is a student type with restricted rights, while admin is an admin user type

Comment: box_user_selection.Text = i.Item("Name" & vbCrLf), aren't you replacing the text over with each loop?

Comment: I thought I can add the columns after another with this, to get the table-look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `SQL.RunQuery("SELECT Name" & "FROM" ""User"")`

are you sure it fills the DS `SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows`?

If yes then,

```
Dim StrVal As String
For i = 0 To SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    StrVal = StrVal & SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Name").ToString()
Next i

box_user_selection.Text = StrVal
```

To see if your SQLDS.Table really returns a row, `Msgbox(SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SQLDS Has value.
If your SQLDS is Dataset, Loop through your SQLDS table by datarow. see example

```
    For Each dr As DataRow In SqlDs.Tables(0).Rows
        box_user_selection.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("Name"))
    Next
```

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean?
SQLDS means datasource, or dataset, right? which means I need to make sure the SQL table is filled with values, which it is.
I also gt that I have to loop through each row and get the values, but I am unsure of how to actually get these values, and then display them in an appropriate textbox row

Comment: yes SQLDS is dataset. Try looping using For Each loop.